# Wingman Wheel with different power supply?

Tags: power, voltage, operational-amplifier

I have an old Wingman Formula Force running on 20V / 1.5A, and I've lost my original cord/power supply.

I have 2 other supples in here, one with 12V / 2.5A
Second is 22V / 1230mA (guessing that's the same as 1.23A?)

Would it work with any of them? Is there any risk of burning the wheel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good idea. But most of the devices like  Wingman Formula Force have 
internal voltage regulators some may don't.And some are very sensitive.

Most probably it 22v one will work.
To make it more sure , more less probable of smoking things up, open the lid
and make sure there are regulators and it locally regulate it.
BTW, if it even works it would give trouble with time.

So I can't give a clear answer for this.

[I have done the same trick with a externally powered hard disk device, it worked !
no troubles yet. ].

Comment: The problem with the 22 V one is that it may supply too little current and cause problems, even if the wheel has internal regulators, depending on what the designers were thinking and how much they were trying to save on the production costs

Comment: I assumed, designers probably keeping a margin when they designing. This will be a problem when device is on it's peak load. If it got regulators , then regulators will shut it down when it detect low voltages. Modern regulator are.

Comment: If @Detrol is asking if 1230 mA is the same as 1.23 A, then they may not be comfortable reverse engineering the circuit to determine the regulators and voltage protections. A more basic answer may be needed.

Comment: I can almost guarantee that there are  significant unregulated sections inside. This is a force-feedback controller, so there is a big motor in there to produce force on the wheel. I really doubt they are regulating the 1.5A the motor likely draws. They're probably just running it straight from the power brick.

Comment: @sandun dhammika But until we see the regulators themselves, we can't be sure that they will shut down. Many regulators don't an instead just provide lower voltage which may or may not be dangerous.